# Почему среда восстановления Windows 11 запускается на диске С вместо скрытого раздела Recovery?

Tags: восстановление, windows-11

Устанавливая Windows 11 на чистую, удалил раздел восстановления с расчётом, что он автоматически сформируется, но он не сформировался. Среда восстановления запускается на диске С (при команде reagentc /enable создается папка Recovery в корне диска и там инициализируется). Создал вручную раздел Recovery, пробовал копировать Winre.wim в раздел Recovery вручную и указывать местоположение образа; пересмотрел всевозможные статьи в интернете, но так и не получается запускать среду в Recovery разделе. Или так и должно быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод команды bcdedit:
[image: Вывод команды bcdedit:]